# Checkbox Select and Deselect functionality in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a "Select All" checkbox on the page, which will deselect and select the below checkboxes.

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="SelectAllCheckBox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="SelectAllCheckBox" />
        <label for="SelectAllCheckBox">Select All</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="TargetsPanel" class="panel" style="display: block;">
    <div class="body stack-calc">
        <table id="TargetsTable" class="tm-list" cellspacing="0">
            <colgroup>
                <col width="20px">
                <col width="20%">
                <col>
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th> Language </th>
                <th> Workflow </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="LanguageName">Arabic</span>
                        <ul class="Publications">
                            <li>
                                <img alt="" src="/test/tt.png">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="tcm:0-235-1" name="tcm:0-235-1" checked="checked">                               
                                <label for="tcm:0-235-1">Test Arabic</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td><select name="_1041" disabled=""><option value="1650">Test</option></select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="LanguageName">Test Chinese (HongKong)</span>
                        <ul class="Publications">
                            <li>
                                <img alt="" src="/test/mm.png">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="tcm:0-368-1" name="tcm:0-368-1" checked="checked">                               
                                <label for="tcm:0-368-1">Test (Traditional Chinese)</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td><select name="_1116" disabled=""><option value="1650">Test2</option></select></td>
                </tr>
                ...
                ...
                ...//It goes on for other checkboxes.
                ...
                ...
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to have have select and deselect functionality on "SelectAllCheckBox" checkbox for below all the checkboxes. There is nothing common in checkbox for doing the mapping excepts they are checkboxes and I want these checkboxes only other will be out of bound.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="tcm:0-235-1" name="tcm:0-235-1" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" id="tcm:0-368-1" name="tcm:0-368-1" checked="checked">
....
....
....
```

Thanks

EDIT:

```
c.SelectAllCheckBox = $("#SelectAllCheckBox"); //I am initializing the existing checkbox id

$evt.addEventHandler(c.SelectAllCheckBox, "click", this.getDelegate(this._onSelectAllCheckBoxClick)); //Here I am adding the event listner

TranslationJob.prototype._onSelectAllCheckBoxClick = function TranslationJob$_onSelectAllCheckBoxClick(headDoc, items)
{
    var p = this.properties;
    var c = p.controls;

    //Here I want code which will deselect and select the checkboxes

};
```

**Required:**
the functionality should work as when master is selected all child should be selected, once master is deselected all child should be deselected and also if any of child checkbox is deselected then master should be deselected and also same if all child gets selected master should gets selected automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pure javascript solution :)
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6sxxZ/6/

```
function get_checkboxes() {
    var cboxes = [];
    var tbl = document.getElementById('TargetsTable');
    var tbody = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var trs = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var cbox;
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
        cboxes.push(cbox = trs[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]);
    }
    return cboxes;
}

var _cboxes = get_checkboxes();
for (var i = 0; i < _cboxes.length; i++) {
    _cboxes[i].onchange = function () {

        var __cboxes = get_checkboxes();
        var all_checked = true;
        for (var j = 0; j < __cboxes.length; j++) {

            if (!__cboxes[j].checked) {
                all_checked = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('SelectAllCheckBox').checked = all_checked;
    }
};

document.getElementById('SelectAllCheckBox').onchange = function () {
    var cboxes = get_checkboxes();
    for (var i = 0; i < cboxes.length; i++) {
        cboxes[i].checked = this.checked;
    }
};
```

Comment: ok thanks Relfor, what if anybody deselect the checkboxes, then it should deselect the master "select all" checkbox as well and its giving error on "this.checked;" saying TypeError: this.checked is undefined

Comment: I added the functionality for that. Is it giving you the error while you run the fiddle or when you try embedding the code in your project?

Comment: Relfor as you know I have already pointed that 'this.checked;' is working for me, please suggest and also if anybody deselect the child checkbox then it should deselect the master as well

Comment: ambiguity. do all the checkboxes need to be unchecked for the 'master' to be unchecked, or is the unchecking of one checkbox sufficient? Since you mentioned the plural 'checkboxes', i implemented the former.

Comment: yeah, actually the functionality should work as when master is selected all child should be selected, once master is deselected all child should be deselected and also if any of child checkbox is deselected then master should be deselected and also same if all child gets selected master should gets selected automatically, and also "this.checked;" does not work for me

Comment: thanks Relfor, how to fix the "this.checked;" issue as this is not supported for me

Comment: may I ask why you are removing this.checked?

Comment: yes and when I run this code in application, it says "Error: TypeError: this.checked is undefined"

Comment: I fixed the this.checked issue, now its giving me "d[a] is undefiened" seems here cboxes.push(cbox = trs[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0]);

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#SelectAllCheckBox', function(){
  $('.Publications input[type=checkbox]').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

it would check all checkboxes which have `class=Publications` once you click on Select All checkox & also uncheck them, if you remove the check.

Further, you can customise the `$('.Publications input[type=checkbox]')` selector to your will to change what checkboxes are checked/unchecked

**[edit]**

for a **Pure JavaScript** solution, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17388573/367985)

Comment: As a side note, you can remove the `this.checked` part to invert the selection (unselect all selected and select all unselected)

Comment: my application page is giving error "TypeError: $(...).toggle is not a function" is there any other way to achieve this

Comment: ^^^Can you show me the error & code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? so I can help you fix the error. thanks

Comment: Gaurish, its a big application and javascript function is some like above, please see my edit. Actually I am adding this functionality to existing application

Comment: Can I have this solution using javascript instead of jquery

Comment: can you clarify that part in your question? there seems to be a tag of jquery at the moment

Comment: yeah sorry for this would remove the same, seems my application is not supporting jquery

Comment: updated my answer with pure js solution, this is not the full code but I think you will get the idea.

Comment: thanks Gaurish, why not on click event? and also if anybody deselect the selected checkboxes then it should deselect the "select all" checkbox

Comment: Gaurish it behaving differently if you click first below checkboxes then it starts behaving the viceversa, please look into this and suggest

Comment: Fixed the bugs, made it `onclick`, also deselects the  main selected checkbox, if any of checkboxes are deselected. now, I am sure you get the idea how how to proceed & add features on your own. Its all about dom,function & events

Answer (score 0):

jquery solution:
**edit**: original question accepted a jquery solution
fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/WF74Y/3/

```
$('#SelectAllCheckBox').change(function () {
    $('div#TargetsPanel table#TargetsTable tr input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Comment: Relfor, I want to select/deselect all checkboxes inside div id "TargetsPanel" >> table id "TargetsTable">> tbody >> tr on the click event of #SelectAllCheckBox

Comment: I checked in fiddle it is not working for me, it is selecting however not deselecting to the checkboxes, can you please check it again

Comment: didn't know you wanted that, updated, the code is even shorter now :)

Comment: Relfor, would appriciate if you can give solution using javascript instead of using jquery...as seems my application is not supporting jquery :(

Answer (score 0):

**A pure javascript solution**

```
var selectAll = document.querySelector('#SelectAllCheckBox');

function checkUncheck() {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.Publications input[type=checkbox]');
    for (var checkbox in checkboxes) {
        if (!checkboxes.hasOwnProperty(checkbox)) continue;
        if (selectAll.checked) {
            checkboxes[checkbox].checked = true;
        } else {
            checkboxes[checkbox].checked = false;
        }
    }
}

function uncheck(){
    selectAll.checked = false;
}
```

now, we need to add these two functions to event. I choose use inline events & its done this way:

1. Add an `onclick` callback to call `checkUncheck()` to `#SelectAllCheckBox`
2. Add an `onclick` callback to call `uncheck` all the other checkbox

you can use [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) & add EventHandlers to do the same thing.

Here is Jsfiddle to show it in working:

- [jsfille demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gary4gar/WqUhP/)

Hope it helps

PS: FYI, I have used `querySelector/querySelectorAll` API leads to much cleaner node & is well supported in all modern browsers. it just doesn't work on IE6/IE7 which are legacy browsers.

Comment: Big problem Gaurish, child checkboxes are generated dynamically so how to track them? they all get renders when page is loaded

Comment: what you mean by `how to track them?` first jquery, then pure-js & now dynamic. your question changes on each answer? what exactly are you trying to do? asking the right question would get the right answer ;)

Comment: Gaurish, I know questions got little changed, however I thought these all should be handled automatically, sorry for all these confusion

Comment: **note** the above solution isn't a cross-browser one.

Comment: @Relfor what parts do you think will cause problems? Also these problem would be present on legacy browsers(IE<9) or on modern ones as well?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` is the issue, nothing else. feel free to use the querying part of my code.

Comment: `querySelector/querySelectorAll` leads to much cleaner node & is [well supported](http://caniuse.com/queryselector), it just doesn't work on IE6/IE7 which are legacy browsers, so we don't care about those anyway

Comment: Agree with that, it provides jquery like querying. When it's not your project and what you implement is not at stake, one cannot simply provide an answer without any warnings about 'legacy browsers' failing and then go on to say 'we don't care about those anyway' in the comments section (fyi: if this is your stance on the issue then it should be there in the content of the answer!). Remember that you are the more knowledgable person here.

Comment: Yes, I have stopped caring/supporting IE6/IE7. so added that in answer.