# .Net MVC Deselecting model checkboxes onclick in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, model-view-controller

I have a model with two lists of SelectListItems:

```
public List<SelectListItem> ChosenLanguages { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> ChosenTemplates { get; set; }
```

I create checkboxes from those two lists for the user to interact with:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <h5>Select languages for certificates</h5>
                <div class="row" style="width:100%">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ChosenLanguages.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ChosenLanguages[i].Selected)

                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ChosenLanguages[i].Text)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ChosenLanguages[i].Value)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ChosenLanguages[i].Text)
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <h5>Select templates for certificates</h5>
                <div class="row" style="width:100%">
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ChosenTemplates.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ChosenTemplates[i].Selected)

                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ChosenTemplates[i].Text)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ChosenTemplates[i].Value)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ChosenTemplates[i].Text)
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now I want to have a new checkbox that will "`onclick`" *deselect* all the checkboxes created above (as the use case requires the user to only select 1 language and 1 template):

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SerialOnly, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onclick = "clearSelected();" } })
```

**My question is** how do I go about deselecting each checkbox from the model in the view through an `onclick`? I have tried to use `JavaScript` and `JQuery` but I cannot figure out how I would access the individual checkboxes in the `List`..

I have tried to use the code from the most upvoted answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387935/checkbox-select-and-deselect-functionality-in-javascript) (the accepted solution does not seem to fit my layout):

```
$(document).on('click', '#SelectAllCheckBox', function () {
        $('.Publications input[type=checkbox]').toggle(this.checked);
    });
```

Where I added the `Publications` name as a `class` to my checkboxes like so:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ChosenTemplates[i].Selected, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "Publications" } })
```

And added the `id` to the new checkbox:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SerialOnly, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SelectAllCheckBox", @onclick = "clearSelected();" } })
```

But this did not work either. I know it will select all instead of deselect, but I just wanted to make the functionality work before changing it to deselect. Any ideas?

Comment: "*Where I added the Publications*" given `$('.Publications input[type=checkbox]')` you would need to add Publications class to a *parent* element, not the checkbox itself - *or* change your selector to `$('input[type=checkbox].Publications')`  (no space)

Comment: Also, `.toggle(this.checked)` will *hide* your other checkboxes, not toggle their values.

Comment: Note: use *either* jquery events *or* html onclick= if you use both, it will just cause confusions - you don't need `$(document).on('click', '#SelectAllCheckBox'` and the `@id=` if you're using onclick= (recommendation is to use js events (vanilla or jquery) over HTML on=)

Comment: My bad, I usually try to avoid using JavaScript and JQuery as much as I can, so I am not very familiar with it. I have tried to first change the code to "`$('input[type=checkbox].Publications')`", this did not do anything. Neither did using the original code and adding the Publications class to the parent element instead. Nothing happens, no value toggling nor hiding. Do you have any other ideas?